# Why was Mordechai dressed in royal clothing a second time?

Tags: clothing, megillat-esther, malchut-royalty, mordechai

Esther 8:15 says

> וּמָרְדֳּכַ֞י יָצָ֣א ׀ מִלִּפְנֵ֣י הַמֶּ֗לֶךְ בִּלְב֤וּשׁ מַלְכוּת֙ תְּכֵ֣לֶת וָח֔וּר וַעֲטֶ֤רֶת זָהָב֙ גְּדוֹלָ֔ה וְתַכְרִ֥יךְ בּ֖וּץ וְאַרְגָּמָ֑ן וְהָעִ֣יר שׁוּשָׁ֔ן צָהֲלָ֖ה וְשָׂמֵֽחָה׃
>
> Mordecai left the king’s presence in royal robes of blue and white, with a magnificent crown of gold and a mantle of fine linen and purple wool. And the city of Shushan rang with joyous cries.

Why was Mordechai accorded the honor of wearing royal clothing a second time? The first being when he was paraded in royal garb by Haman (ibid 6:8-10)

I am seeking answers based on the text itself or explicit sources in chazal if possible

Comment: Does the fact that it was the second time have any relevance or is that just your way of identifying which time you are asking about?

Comment: @DoubleAA the latter, the first time there was a reason that was indicated in the text. I'm looking for a reason for the second time

Answer (score 1):

*Alshich* ([Esther 8:15](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.8.15?with=Alshich)) explains that *Mordechai* was honored the first time with royal clothing, etc. as a reward for his wearing sackcloth, etc.

However, this was while the Jews were not yet saved, and therefore it wasn't a complete reward. Therefore, when the Jews were saved, he was once again honored with the royal clothing, and this time is was a full and complete reward for his humility.

Comment: thank you for providing this answer. i have edited the question to mention that I am seeking answers based on the text in question if possible

Answer (score 0):

Consider the description of Yosef when he was appointed to the position of second to the king. As the Prime Minister, Mordechai (like Yosef) would be required to wear the garments appropriate to his position. The question should be why Mordechai did not start wearing the appropriate garments once the need for *sak ve'eifer* was over (after Purim). After the initial time (when he had to wear royal garments by command of the king), he resumed his mourning garments. Thus the answers cited below, show why he did not dress in *royal garments* until then.

[Esther 8:8](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16481#v=8&showrashi=true) shows that this is the time when Mordechai was actually given the authority to issue decrees in the name of the king and sealed with the king's ring.

> And you-write about the Jews as you see fit, in the name of the king,
>   and seal [it] with the king's ring, for a writ that is written in the
>   name of the king and sealed with the king's ring cannot be rescinded."

Malbim on [Esther 8:5](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Esther/8.15#e0n6) says

> שמרדכי יצא להודיע צדקת מרדכי שלא קבל על עצמו שום גדולה עד שנכון לבו
>   בטוח  שהיתה אורה ותשועה לאחיו האומללים שאז יצא בלבוש מלכות לא קודם

Mordechai refrained from dressing as befitted his (now royal) position until he had been able to complete the saving of the Yehudim and they could rejoice.

The Chachmei Tzorfas there point out that the language is specifically set up to parallel the mourning when the original decree was issued and contrast what Mordechai wore then.

> ומרדכי יצא מלפני המלך – במקום: ויצא בתוך העיר (אסתר ד׳:א׳) ויצעק צעקה.
>   בלבוש מלכות – במקום: וילבש שק ואפר (אסתר ד׳:ב׳). ועטרת זהב גדולה
>   ותכריך בוץ וארגמן – ובמקום: העיר שושן נבוכה (אסתר ג׳:ט״ו): והעיר שושן
>   צהלה ושמחה.

Comment: I don't understand how this explains why he would have any need or permission to wear these clothes

Comment: @rikitikitembo I added more detail to explain why the delay. In a royal court, everyone has to dress in the way appropriate to his position.

Comment: but this is royal clothing,  haman wasn't even wearing clothing like this

Comment: @rikitikitembo Who says. Haman was wearing the approprate clothing for his position, but never stopped so there was no need to say so specifically. Mordechai had been dress in mourning and had deliberately not put on the *royal cloting* (though he no longer wore mourning) until that point. Thus, the megillah specifically mentioned it. This is like what the Torah said regarding Yosef.

Comment: @rikitikitembo Contrarily, what would give Mordechai the right to wear royal garb if he's not serving as part of the royal staff? When Haman rode him, Mordechai wasn't part of the staff (was he?) But the king commanded Haman to dress him that way.